# Pivot Table using OpenXML Power Tool in C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-powertools

I am trying to generate Pivot tables programatically using C# OpenXML Power tool. I am trying to export the raw data to sheet 1 and Pivot table on sheet1.
When I am adding an integer column as a data value, Pivot table is generated with proper values. But, if I select a non-integer column,count and sum generated is always zero. Following is the snapshot of the excel file it is generating.[image]

Data in Pivot.txt is in format as mentioned below:
Year,Quarter,Region,Category,Product,Amount
2010,Q1,North,Bicycles,B100,3448.00
2010,Q1,North,Bicycles,B200,8448.00
2010,Q1,North,Bicycles,B300,922.00 
2010,Q1,North,Accessories,Mirrors,303.00 
2010,Q1,North,Accessories,Carriers,455.00 
2010,Q1,South,Bicycles,B100,2887.00
2010,Q1,South,Bicycles,B200,4477.00
2010,Q1,South,Bicycles,B300,1011.00 
2010,Q1,South,Accessories,Mirrors,80.00 
2010,Q1,South,Accessories,Carriers,205.00

Following is the code I am using:

```
private static void generatePivot()
        {
            int row;
            row = 1;
            int maxColumn = 1;
            using (OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument streamDoc = OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument.CreateSpreadsheetDocument())
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = streamDoc.GetSpreadsheetDocument())
                {
                    WorksheetPart sheet = WorksheetAccessor.AddWorksheet(doc, "Range");
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader source = new System.IO.StreamReader("../../PivotData.txt"))
                    {
                        while (!source.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            string line = source.ReadLine();
                            if (line.Length > 3)
                            {
                                string[] fields = line.Split(',');
                                int column = 1;
                                foreach (string item in fields)
                                {
                                    double num;
                                    if (double.TryParse(item, out num))
                                        WorksheetAccessor.SetCellValue(doc, sheet, row, column++, num);
                                    else
                                        WorksheetAccessor.SetCellValue(doc, sheet, row, column++, item);
                                }
                                maxColumn = column - 1;
                            }
                            row++;
                        }
                    }
                    sheet.PutXDocument();
                    WorksheetAccessor.SetRange(doc, "Sales", "Range", 1, 1, row - 1, maxColumn);
                    WorksheetPart pivot = WorksheetAccessor.AddWorksheet(doc, "Pivot");
                    WorksheetAccessor.CreatePivotTable(doc, "Sales", pivot);


                    // Configure pivot table rows, columns, data and filters
                    //WorksheetAccessor.AddPivotAxis(doc, pivot, "Year", WorksheetAccessor.PivotAxis.Column);
                    WorksheetAccessor.AddPivotAxis(doc, pivot, "Quarter", WorksheetAccessor.PivotAxis.Column);
                    WorksheetAccessor.AddPivotAxis(doc, pivot, "Category", WorksheetAccessor.PivotAxis.Row);
                    //WorksheetAccessor.AddPivotAxis(doc, pivot, "Product", WorksheetAccessor.PivotAxis.Row);
                    WorksheetAccessor.AddDataValue(doc, pivot, "Product");
                    WorksheetAccessor.AddPivotAxis(doc, pivot, "Region", WorksheetAccessor.PivotAxis.Page);
            }
            streamDoc.GetModifiedSmlDocument().SaveAs("../../NewPivot.xlsx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you can change the library, I suggest usage of epplus instead of openxml, it's more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting EPPlus...I was able to overcome this issue using EPPPlus...